# Can php forward a contact form completer to a different URL?

Tags: php, forms, forwarding

My site has a simple, PHP powered contact form that returns an on page result, when the user clicks send. I would like to modify it to forward them to a URL holding a thank you page. Can any one point me at the basic code line for that? The contents of my `send.php` are here:

```
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", 'info@blendmarketing.co.uk');
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

function ValidateEmail($email) {
    $regex = '/([a-z0-9_.-]+)'. # name
    '@'. # at
    '([a-z0-9.-]+){2,255}'. # domain & possibly subdomains
    '.'. # period
    '([a-z]+){2,10}/i'; # domain extension 

    if($email == '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        $eregi = preg_replace($regex, '', $email);
    }
    return empty($eregi) ? true : false;
}

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post) {
    $name    = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email   = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    $error = '';

    // Check name
    if(!$name) {
        $error .= 'Name required! ';
    }

    // Check email
    if(!$email) {
        $error .= 'E-mail required! ';
    }

    if($email && !ValidateEmail($email)) {
        $error .= 'E-mail address is not valid! ';
    }

    // Check message
    if(!$message) {
        $error .= "Please enter your message!";
    }

    if(!$error) {
        $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
             "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail) {
            echo 'OK';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="errormsg">'.$error.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: replace echo 'OK'; with header('location: ...') or a meta refresh?

Answer (score 1):

You could send this header:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Make sure, that the header is sent, before any other output. Replace the line `echo 'OK';` with `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`.

Comment: When you say 'Make sure, that the header is sent, before any other output' do you mean move the line with the header call to a point just before the line that sends the message?

Comment: Yes, you have to return the headers firstly. `<?php echo 'Hello'; header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); ?> Will produce an error, not vice versa.

Comment: So it should be: 'if(!$error)
  {
   $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
     "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
    ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
   
   if($mail)
     //echo 'OK';
    header('Location: http://www.blendmarketing.co.uk/contact_thankyou.html'); 
  }
'

Comment: This seems to result in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should do it before any other output, or with output buffering:

```
if($success)
{
   header('location: /thankyou.html');
   die;
}
```